# Why does google oauth offer refresh token for native-app while not for Javascript web app?

Tags: google-oauth

When reading the doc of google oauth API, I found that it does not offer refresh token to Javascript (JS) web app, as mentioned in below link. It says "Refresh tokens are not typically used in client-side (JavaScript) web applications."
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

However in the following page it offers the refresh token (as well as client secret) to native app. Seems strange that both JS web app and native app are not confidential. Shoudn't it also not to offer refresh token and client secret to native app?
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A refresh token in a client sided application where anyone could view source and see the refresh token and client id and client secret. This would mean that anyone could then create a new access token to access the data.

If I understand what you mean by native apps they are run on a users machine and there by the only one in theory who would be accessing that machine would be the user who is accessing their own data. Native apps can also better protect the various secrets from both the user and other apps. So while it is still an exposure risk - the risk is significantly lower.

Use a server side web language if you want a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks a lot. And another question for web client with server side, is the the "Authorization Code Flow" more safe than the "PKCE flow"? 
PKCE is just to verify the client that initiated the initial authentication request is also the same that uses the authorization code to get the real tokens, but it cannot involve client credentials (client_secret), which is used in the "Authorization Code Flow" to make the flow more safe?